# Mobile Push API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

I have a question on Message Keys for Mobile Push Batch API. I tried to search the documentation but could not find a relevant answer.

Please note that we are using REST API for the calls.

a. Do we need to provide Message keys for the Alert Title & Icon that appears on the device? 
b. Can these default from the setup of the message itself vs being passed in each API call or some other method 
c. What sort of keys should be configured at the application level in the application definition 
d. Is there an example setup for the application keys in place which we could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The AndroidLearning App](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid) has sample code.

The data portion of the payload you receive on the device will resemble:

```
    {
      "alert": "Analytics Verification Alert",
      "_m": "MTExOjFxNDow3",
      "sound": "default",
      "et_big_pic": "http://short.url/2k3Qjzx",
      "sent_timestamp": "Fri, 31 Mar 2017 14:01:59 GMT"
    }
```

The depicted payload is incomplete.  The documentation should guide you to the other properties you can provide for icon, etc.